# What type should the argument be if it's a function

Tags: typescript

I started learning typescript and I can't figure it out what type should be the argument if it's a function in callback. What's the syntax for this function's type?

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

export const tryCatch = (func) => {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      await func(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
};
```

[image]

Comment: `(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void> | void`

Comment: @vr. I don't understand how to use it, can you explain a little?

Comment: That is the type of the function. You can annotate the parameter with it. If you don't understand, have you tried referring to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html)?

Comment: @vr. i think i got it. does this mean that my controller, which will be wrapped in a try catch, does not return anything?

Comment: `void` means that you don't know and don't care what it returns. Most of the time, it's `undefined` (case in point: `console.log`).

Comment: @vr Even though the code does not expect any return-value for func, it might be still returning something, I would therefore recommend to define the type of func slightly differently:
`(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<unknown>`

Comment: @jimmyorpheus Makes no difference here since they aren't using the returned value. It's more semantically correct to use void here.

Comment: @vr My argument is, not to exclude functions only because
they return something, that we dont care about anyway.
It is easy to imagine a function func that does exactly 
what is needed in that context but additionally returns something.
Since the return value can simply be ignored, a defintion of void or Promise<void> would
place an unnecessary restriction on the functions that are allowed to be passed and used here.

Comment: @jimmyorpheus [How?](https://tsplay.dev/Nll0BN)

Comment: @jimmyorpheus Oh, I did not mean to add `Promise<void>` to my original comment. Just `void` will do. Yes, that would mean the editor would flag `await` as being pointless, but `Promise<unknown>` would then require callbacks to return a promise. I think `unknown | Promise<unknown>` will do.

Comment: @vr You are right: Without Promises, it is no problem to pass a function that returns something even if void is defined as return-type. I wasn't aware of that and it's really good to know.

But as you recognized yourself, it's not the same with a generic return-type like Promise<void>.
A Promise<string> is not accepted where a type of a Promise<void> is expected.

[ts playground example](https://tsplay.dev/NB8PkW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like is probably what you're looking for:

```js
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

export const tryCatch = (func: (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<unknown>) => {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      await func(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Just regurgitating code is rarely a good answer, especially when the OP is admittedly learning. Providing links to documentation is usually good, as is explaining why you chose the specific code you wrote.

Comment: As discussed above and demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/NB8PkW) the Promise<void> return-type places an unnecessary restriction on the functions that are allowed to be passed to tryCatch. A return-type of Promise<unknown> would therefore be preferable here.